# Is it possible that Parallel.ForEach Loop will handle all my collection in order

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I am using `Parallel.ForEach Loop` with my collection and i saw that this process my collection in some arbitrary oder or maybe divide my collection into pices so Is it possible that `Parallel.ForEach` Loop will handle all my collection in order ?

Edit

```
list<MyData> mylist;

private void StartTransmit(ObservableCollection<WiresharkFile> files)
        {
    cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cancellationTokenSource.Token;
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
    {
        try
        {
                Parallel.For(0, files.Count, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5},
                i =>
                {
                    if (token.IsCancellationRequested)
                        return;

                    //do work...
                    files[i].ProcessFile();
                });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        { }

    }, cancellationTokenSource.Token,
   TaskCreationOptions.None,
   TaskScheduler.Default).ContinueWith(
        t =>
        {

        }
    );
}
```

Comment: Lets say you have 5 threads executing 5 elements of your collection, if thread 3 finish its task earlier than other threads, it will process the 6th element of your collection and, IMHO, you don't have control on which thread processes which element. is this the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Processing the collection inorder will degrade the effect of parallalism drastically, it may even lead to slower execution over the sequential `foreach`.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Are you asking how to make sure that the *start* of processing each element happens in order? Why would that matter to you?

Comment: *What* do you mean "in order" and why should it matter? Besides, *how* do you expect data to be processed concurrently and still maintain order? One CPU is always going to finish faster than another and start processing the next input file. If you explain what your *actual* requirement is, we may be able to help. Eg do you need to know the dates used in each file? Do you want to calculate running aggregates or other stuff that requires state?

Comment: This seems like a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Having a problem with X but asking about the assumed solution Y instead of X. In your case, depending on the *actual* requirement, you could assign a timestamp to each data point and use it for a second step of processing, you could partition the input data to batches of 5 with a custom partitioner, you could use PLINQ with `AsOrdered()` or an ActionBlock with MaxDOP 5. Each option solves some problems easily, some become much harder.

Answer (score 1):

`Parallel.ForEach` is made to work parallel. if your collection has very big logic which requires outside resources then only it will work in random order because it does not wait for one iteration to get complete. If you want to process collection in order then `Paraller.ForEach` is bad idea. Go with `foreach`.

One of the solution could be setting `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`  property of `ParallelOptions` class to 1.
like

```
Parallel.For(0, 1000, new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 },
  i =>
  {

  });
```

Comment: I forgat to mention that i want to be able to control the number of concurrent threds and with Parallel.ForEach i have this property

Comment: Shoehorning a parallel job into 1 parallel task isn't going to help, you might as well just use `foreach` then.

Comment: I have mention that too in my answer but I also wanted to put some light on  MaxDegreeOfParallelism which was possibly not known to OP and is one of the solution.

Comment: change MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5 to MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1

Comment: If you want several threads then your code will run on multiple threads, so execution will be out of order. You can't run sequential execution on multiple thread. This is the reason behind using Multithreaded programming